# cant open any folders and files in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

PS C:\web development projects\3.3+Postman> nodemon index.js
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

no files and folders are opening like its always the welcome page i have to run it as administrator but then im having the above issue and other issues like it

well i tried opening my folders in various ways but none worked

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), after that improve your question by using [edit] to make your question (more) [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (Currently it is not ....)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.